# Twilio browser-to-browser

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio

I'm going through the twilio quickstart and have a problem - my call button doesn't trigger a request for twilio;

```
namespace twilioMvc.Controllers
{
    public class BrowserToBrowserController : Controller
    {
        string accountSid;
        string authToken;
        string appSid;
        string clientName;
        string token;
        public BrowserToBrowserController()
        {
            NameValueCollection manager = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings") as NameValueCollection;
            accountSid = manager["acSID"];
            authToken = manager["authToken"];
            // put your Twilio Application Sid here
            appSid = manager["appSID"];
            // put your default Twilio Client name here
            clientName = "jenny";

            var capability = new TwilioCapability(accountSid, authToken);
            capability.AllowClientOutgoing(appSid);
            capability.AllowClientIncoming(clientName);
            token = capability.GenerateToken();
        }

        public ActionResult Index(string name)
        {
            if (name != "" && name != null)
            {
                clientName = name;
            }

            var client = new Client() { clientName = clientName, token = token };
            return View("Index", client);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Call(string PhoneNumber)
        {
            // put your default Twilio Client name here, for when a phone number isn't given
            string number = "jenny";

            // get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
            if (PhoneNumber != null)
            {
                number = PhoneNumber;
            }

            var response = new XElement("Response");
            response.Add(new XElement("Dial", new XElement("Client", number)));                               

            return this.Content(response.Value, "text/xml");

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the page code

```
@model twilioMvc.Models.Client

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Client Monkey 5</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.3/twilio.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="//static0.twilio.com/resources/quickstart/client.css"
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Twilio.Device.setup('@Model.token');

        Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
            $("#log").text("Client '@Model.clientName' is ready");
        });

        Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
            $("#log").text("Error: " + error.message);
        });

        Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
            $("#log").text("Successfully established call");
        });

        Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
            $("#log").text("Call ended");
        });

        Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
            $("#log").text("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
            // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio
            conn.accept();
        });

        function call() {
            // get the phone number or client to connect the call to
            params = { "PhoneNumber": $("#number").val() };
            Twilio.Device.connect(params);
        }

        function hangup() {
            Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="call" onclick="call();">
        Call
    </button>

    <button class="hangup" onclick="hangup();">
        Hangup
    </button>

    <input type="text" id="number" name="number"
           placeholder="Enter a phone number or client to call" />

    <div id="log">Loading pigeons...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, when I click my call button there should be call to twilio app and then it should call my site with void route(filled in my apllication section on twilio site) but there is a trouble. Could you please help me?

Comment: Try using `$("number")` instead of `$("#number")`.

Comment: There is no problem with getting data from number field.

Comment: What is the error you are getting then? Have you done any debugging? Where does your code fail?

Comment: There are no errors. Just nothing going on.

Comment: Try attaching a debugger and step through your code to find out where the problem is. Otherwise, it is likely just going to be a guessing game for everyone.

Comment: As you maybe know you should publish application for registration voice callback from twilio. I have published it on server where I can't install debudder. Could you please provide a method how it can be possible?

Comment: I don't think `div` tags have a `.text` property. You may want to assign your display text to the `.innerHTML` property of the `div` element.

Comment: Also, can you not set your local machine up to emulate the server all of this gets installed to? You should really have some kind of way to run your development code in a way that allows you to do some kind of debugging. Can you set your server up to allow remote debugging? If nothing else though, you could add some "debug" statements to your code that either writes to the screen or to a trace log somewhere.

Comment: my fault, there is an error in twilio.js file - Object.assign is undefined - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed an error with adding to browser polyfill for Object.assign.
But I have another issue with immediate hangup my browser-to browser call.

Comment: This doesn't seem right! The Twilio library should provide all the methods it requires. Could you email me at philnash@twilio.com with the browser you are testing this in and the error message you got?